# Missing Identifier when using .toArray

Tags: java, arrays, identifier

I am working on a program which uses both linear and binary methods of searching. Although I am quite new to coding and I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly in this situation. Here is the code I think should be relavent(Let me know if you need to see more):

```
ArrayList <Books> list = new ArrayList <Books>();

Books[] bookslist = new Books[list.size()];
list.toArray(bookslist);
```

The issue is in the third line. Although I have seen many similar examples which use the same pattern of code, mine does not seem to work. It just tells me that and identifier is expected.

As I said I am pretty new to this, so I would appreciate any input or thoughts on how I can correct this issue. Although, please try to keep this simple (or at least simply explained) so I can hopefully understand!

Thanks guys!

Comment: Please add the tag as the programming language being used

Comment: I can confirm the above works in Java (which is what this looks like) ... unless OP is not using Java. Unless "Books" is also a collection, idiomatically you should not be giving a singular noun plural name ... just as a FYI

Comment: I am using Java with NetBeans. Perhaps I should post all of my code. Would that perhaps help?

Comment: The code you have is correct. Not giving any error on my environment. Either you have an import problem or probably you have the code in the class directly (should be inside the method).

Comment: I do have import recommendations although when I add them, they are not used and the issue persists. I added the code to a pastebin in a comment on the last reply if you want to take a peak at that.

Answer (score 0):

This is the declaration of the toArray() method of ArrayList class that you used.

```
public<T> T[] toArray(T[] a)
```

This means in your case, calling this method will **return** the Books array and not store it in the variable that you passed i.e. **bookslist**

Make the changes in the third line as shown below since the method returns the array and you need to store it somewhere (in your case, in the variable **bookslist**)

```
ArrayList <Books> list = new ArrayList <Books>(); 
Books[] bookslist = new Books[list.size()]; 
bookslist = list.toArray(bookslist);
```

However, there is another overloaded toArray method for ArrayList. The declaration is as follows.

```
public Object[] toArray()
```

This means, if you call `list.toArray()` , it will return an Object of type **Books[]**

You may ask, what's the difference between the two and it's usage. Well, the parametrized version allows you to have more control on your code.

For example.

If you have

```
ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

If you call `intList.toArray()` , it will return **Integer[]**
But, if you call `intList.toArray(new Long[intList.size]())` , then it will return **Long[]**

Comment: Using that code: Cannot find symbol bookslist. Also, still an identifier issue. Did I do something wrong? Also, I tried both booklist (as you put) and bookslist(Which I think is what you meant).

Comment: Is the bookslist variable declared in the same scope as that to where you are calling the toArray() method? Maybe you are declaring bookslist in some loop or if else block and calling the toArray method outside the loop

Comment: To be honest, the only mention of the bookslist variable is in the code I shared. Although maybe a full look of the code can explain what's happening better than I can. Here is a pastebin of the code: http://pastebin.com/AaNXCw7A

Comment: Did you miss any of the starting lines? The identifiers list and bookslist, are they elements of a class? Or declared inside a method?

Comment: The only class I have is the Books class. I do not think they are in a method. Why would they need to be? I don't usually place my arraylists in methods.

Comment: In Java, everything should be inside a class. Your Books class only has title and id elements and the Books parametrized constructor. You can choose to have the ArrayList list and bookslist in Books or any other class. But they should be in a class

Comment: There is another method, binarySearch(). This method belongs to which class? I presume, list and bookslist belong to the same class, but as class elements. All the processing and logic should be inside methods. So create a new method and put `ArrayList <Books> list = new ArrayList <Books>(); Books[] bookslist = new Books[list.size()]; list.toArray(bookslist);` there

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix my issues. I simply moved the following lines into my findButton method.

```
    Books[] bookslist = new Books[list.size()]; 
    list.toArray(bookslist);

    int referenceNum = Integer.parseInt(inputField.getText());
```

The list.toArray(bookslist); would not function outside of a method. So this fixed my issues perfectly. Thanks for the help guys!